# UIImagePickerControllerCameraCaptureModePhoto not working in IOS 7

Tags: ios7, photolibrary

In IOS6 I am using following method to get photo from I Pad photo Library.But now its not working for IOS7

```
UIImagePickerController* picker = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init]; 
    picker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerCameraCaptureModePhoto; 
    picker.delegate = self; 

    UIPopoverController *popover = [[UIPopoverController alloc] initWithContentViewController:picker];
    [popover presentPopoverFromBarButtonItem:sender permittedArrowDirections:UIPopoverArrowDirectionUp animated:YES];
    [picker release], picker = nil;
```

What is issue with IOS7

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you can use custom Frame and load the popover ;)

```
[popOver presentPopoverFromRect:CGRectMake(self.view.frame.size.width-50, 50, 10, 10) inView:self.view permittedArrowDirections:UIPopoverArrowDirectionAny animated:YES];
```

Check out [UIImagePickerController crash only on iOS 7 - iPad](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18939537/uiimagepickercontroller-crash-only-on-ios-7-ipad)

Answer (score 0):

Its Probably an iOS 7 Bug. Probably your  personal hotspot is on at the moment try to turn it off at and run the application