# UIImagePickerController works on simulator, crashes on device

Tags: iphone, crash, ios-simulator, ios7, uiimagepickercontroller

Here is how i use my IPC:

```
ipc = nil; // reset (camera may be running)
ipc = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
[ipc setDelegate:self];

ipc.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypePhotoLibrary;

[self presentViewController:ipc animated:YES completion:^(void){
    [self cancelShoot];
}];
```

It works well on 3GS with iOS 6, also i have no issues on iOS 7 simulator. While testing on iOS 7 devices (iPod 5 gen, iPhone 4, iPhone 5) it always crashes.

Is there anything new to the latest OS that i should be aware of?

Comment: Most probably your method call [self cancelShoot]; crashes your app, debug into it.

Comment: try commenting first line ipc=nil and [self cancelshoot] and see is it crashing still?

Comment: Sounds like a dup of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18939537/uiimagepickercontroller-crash-only-on-ios-7-ipad

Comment: Tanks for comments, removing `ipc = nil;` was a right thing. still i have no idea why was it a problem...

Answer (score 0):

Is "ipc" a pointer? Given how you are setting sourceType it looks like it isn't..